# Google map links that control the infowindow like the marker does

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to create a list of links dynamically from an array of objects that control the infowindow from the marker within my Google map.

For example I have an array called businesses and the links should be displayed as businesses[0].name, businesses[1].name etc...

When you click on the link, it will display the info box that it coriltes withit just as if you had clicked on the marker. I also have it set so that wen you click another marker, the previous info box closes and the new one opens.

here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
  #map_canvas { height: 480px }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:620px; height:480px"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var infowindow;

    (function(){
        google.maps.Map.prototype.markers = new Array();

        google.maps.Map.prototype.addMarker = function(marker){
            this.markers[this.markers.length] = marker;
        }

        google.maps.Map.prototype.getMarkers = function() {
            return this.markers
        }

        google.maps.Map.prototype.clearMarkers = function() {
            if(infowindow) {
                infowindow.close();
            }

            for(var i=0; i<this.markers.length; i++){
                this.markers[i].set_map(null);
            }
        }

    })();

    var geocoder;
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var businesses = new Array();
        business = {
            name:"Columbia Gorge Blue Grass",
            description:"July 22-25, 2010 at the Skamania County Fairgrounds",
            address:codeAddress("1003 south 6th Ave, Kelso WA 98626"),
            lat:46.72,
            lng:-119.55,
            url:"http://www.columbiagorgebluegrass.net/",
            business_type:"Getaway"
        };
        businesses[0] = business;

        business = {
            name:"Chips Casino Palace",
            description:"We Deal in Fun! La Center, WA",
            lat:45.72,
            lng:-121.55,
            url:"http://www.chipscasino.com/",
            business_type:"Golf"
        };
        businesses[1] = business; 

        business = {
            name:"Skamania County Fair & Timber Carnival",
            description:"August 11-15, 2010 at the Skamania County Fairgrounds",
            lat:45.50,
            lng:-122.55,
            url:"http://www.chipscasino.com/",
            business_type:"Wine"
        };
        businesses[2] = business; 

        //This is where the map positions to when the page is loaded
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(46.88, -120.00);
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 6,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        for (var i = 0; i < businesses.length; i++) {
            //alert(i);
            if(businesses[i].business_type == "Wine"){
                //http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|00CC99|000000
                var icon = 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/wineyard.png';
            }else if(businesses[i].business_type == "Golf"){
                var icon = 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/golf.png';
            }else{
                var icon = 'http://google-maps-icons.googlecode.com/files/festival.png';
            }

            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(businesses[i].lat, businesses[i].lng);
            map.addMarker(createMarker(businesses[i].name,latlng));
         }

        function createMarker(name, latlng) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:latlng, 
            map: map,
            icon: icon,
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
          infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: name});
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          console.log();
        });


        return marker;
      }


    function codeAddress(address) {
        var this_address = address;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': this_address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            return results[0].geometry.lat;
          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
          }
        });
      }      


        }


        $(document).ready(function(){
            initialize();    
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if I need to add another eventlistener or add a function call or what.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a lookup array of IDs of businesses to Google points indicating the latlng of different businesses. When you click on a link, it would also have the business ID somewhere. You can then get the proper latlng, then call "new InfoWindow()" with the proper "position" passed in as part of the options: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindowOptions

Comment: Can you give me a code example? I'm not quite sure I follow. Thanks!